# Python patch internal class __call__ method

Tags: python, pytest

I have a class B that I want to unit test. The class internally instantiates another class A and calls it via its **call** method. How do I patch class A and its **init** and __call__methods?

```
class A:
    def __init__():
        ....
        
    def __call__():
        ....

class B:
    
    def my_method():
        a = A()
        a()
        
def test_b_my_method():
...
```

Comment: Why do you need to patch them? I'd consider redesigning `B` to accept a class argument that defaults to `A`, but can be easily replaced with something less expensive for testing.

Comment: https://www.fugue.co/blog/2016-02-11-python-mocking-101 covers the basics, and https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html shows more of the specifics.  If you're familiar with those pages, please update your question with things you've tried.

Comment: I understand if I can inject A into B I can easily mock it. But I can't so I rely on patching it to mock it effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorators for that

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 1

    def __call__(self):
        return self._foo + 1

class B:
    def my_method(self):
        a = A()
        return a()

def patch_init(fn):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        fn(*args, **kwargs) # calls A.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._foo = 2
    return wrap

def patch_call(fn):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        res = fn(*args, **kwargs) # calls A.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return res * 2
    return wrap

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # unpatched
    b = B()
    print(b.my_method()) # prints 2 (self._foo + 1)
    # patched
    A.__init__ = patch_init(A.__init__)
    A.__call__ = patch_call(A.__call__)
    b = B()
    print(b.my_method()) # prints 6 (self._foo + 1) * 2
```

Comment: Thank you for you example. But as far as I understand patch_init calls internall A.__init__ and patch_cal calls internally A.__call__. I want to mock these methods, no to call them.

Comment: to not call `A.__init__` replace `fn(*args, **kwargs)` with your mock function